# React-slick and Nuka-carousel not working in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: reactjs, react-slick

I import React-slick and Nuka-carousel in my project. Its working fine in opera and chrome but in Mozilla Firefox only dots and arrow are visible.
 [image]

[image]

1.Mozilla Firefox View.
2.Chrome View

Answer (score 1):

Check you images which you are using in react slick. And check once dynamic slides rendering. go through this [enter link description here](https://github.com/akiran/react-slick/issues/328)